# Cannot I use functions and call them as mentioned in the code below?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am getting the following error message in few lines- "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions". I am new to React js.

```
class Menu extends Component{
   constructor(props){
     super(props);

   this.state={
     value1: "Link 1",
     value2: "Link 2",
     value3: "Link 3"
   }
 }

   render(){
     function Click1(){
       <h2>{this.state.value1}</h2>


     }
     function Click2(){
       <h2>{this.state.value2}</h2>


     }
     function Click3(){
       <h2>{this.state.value3}</h2>


     }

   return(
     <div>

     <button  onClick={Click1}>Link 1</button><br></br>
     <button onClick={Click2}>Link 2</button><br></br>
     <button onClick={Click3}>Link 3</button><br></br>


 {/*   
     /* <a  onClick={Click1}>Link 1</a><br></br>
     <a onClick={Click2}>Link 2</a><br></br>
     <a onClick={Click3}>Link 3</a><br></br>  */}

 </div>
   )



 }

 }
```

The expected output is :- 
When I click on any one of the links ,that should appear as text in the next line

Comment: @keikai there are a few more issues than simply not returning a value in the functions. Asish, may I suggest you review the React website, it explains many of the details and feature of React, especially starting with what JSX is, what React renders. There are also mountains of demos and tutorials for basic Hello World pages.

Comment: @Asish I've tried a solution for you. lemme know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried this for you:

What this does is defines 3 handlers for showing the link or hiding, basically toggles on click of button for show/hide.

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value1: "Link 1",
      showValue1: false,
      value2: "Link 2",
      showValue2: false,
      value3: "Link 3",
      showValue3: false
    };
  }

  click1 = () => {
    this.setState({ showValue1: !this.state.showValue1 });
  };

  click2 = () => {
    this.setState({ showValue2: !this.state.showValue2 });
  };

  click3 = () => {
    this.setState({ showValue3: !this.state.showValue3 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.click1()}>Link 1</button>
        {this.state.showValue1 && <h2>{this.state.value1}</h2>}
        <br />
        <button onClick={() => this.click2()}>Link 2</button>
        {this.state.showValue2 && <h2>{this.state.value2}</h2>}
        <br />
        <button onClick={() => this.click3()}>Link 3</button>
        {this.state.showValue3 && <h2>{this.state.value3}</h2>}
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It did work,but I dont understand what you did. And what was the problem with my code that showed error?

Comment: react can update a particular state for you. depending on the state you can decide to show a certain html or not. I made onClick handler for you with react state which can be toggled. React cannot inject html for you - not like the way you had it.